# how to pass a string value to an array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Edit:

Now I change the array to range:`Set arrDeviceType = ScriptSheet.Range("P2:P" & LastApar)`
But I still get the error of `Application-definedorobject-defined error` at `arrDeviceType(X, 1).Resize(I - 2, 0) = "Internet"`

---

My VBA script has problem with this line

```
arrDeviceType(X, 1).Resize(I - 2, 0) = "Internet"
```

arrDeviceType is set as a variant, it's cell value is "Internet System", I need to compare the column with "Internet System" to another worksheet column with "Internet", but they mean the same thing. Since I need to match these two values, so I want to make the script recognise the "Internet System" as same as "Internet" in one worksheet first without making actual changes to the worksheet. So I stored everything in the column into arrDeviceType `arrDeviceType = ScriptSheet.Range("P2:P" & LastApar).Value`.

So the question is how should I do this? I have done the same to a date value, change it to the first day of the month, like this `arrOpenDate(X, 1) = arrOpenDate(X, 1) - Day(arrOpenDate(X, 1)) + 1` and it works, so I'm trying to achive the same with this string value.

The related code posted below, there are three pairs of strings need to be matched:

```
    I = 1
    X = 1
    Do While arrDeviceType(I, 1) = "Internet System"
    I = I + 1
    Loop
    arrDeviceType(X, 1).Resize(I - 2, 0) = "Internet"
    X = I
    OPS = X
    Do While arrDeviceType(OPS, 1) = "Other production system"
    OPS = OPS + 1
    Loop

    arrDeviceType(X, 1).Resize(OPS - X, 0) = "DR"
    X = OPS
    DR = X
    Do While arrDeviceType(DR, 1) = "System subject to disaster recovery"
    DR = DR + 1
    Loop
    arrDeviceType(X, 1).Resize(DR - X, 0) = "DR"
```

Comment: Does `arrDeviceType` contain a range or the values of a range?

Comment: @GSerg it contains a range of values as `arrDeviceType = ScriptSheet.Range("P2:P" & LastApar).Value`, values are strings as well.

Comment: If it contains an array of Variants, it does not have a `Resize` method, neither can you assign multiple array members in one assignment operation. All these features a provided by `Range`, if you need them, store the `Range` instead.

Comment: @GSerg But if I change it to `Range`, will the actual value in the worksheet change?

Comment: Yes it will. Moreover, if you don't change it to a Range, the actual values on the worksheet will not change.

Comment: You can't resize a range to 0 column width.